# InvalidModuleDescriptorException when running my first java app

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have started learning Java and encountered a problem when trying to run my first program as given below:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

On Eclipse Photon I encounter this error when running it:

```
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Thomas\eclipse-workspace\HelloWorld\bin
    Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: HelloWorld.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

I looked and there is my .class file in bin directory and my .java in the `src` directory.

Is that normal? How do I fix that?

Comment: Looks like Jave 9. You have to put the class in a package;

Comment: Add the following statement as first line in your code: `package example;`Eclipse will show you an error. Use the _Quick Help_ and choose "Move ..."

Answer (score 87):

I was getting the same error. Deleting the ***module-info.java*** file solved it for me.

Comment: This fixed my problem too.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: nice solution! Thank you,

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: This answer should get green tick. Thank you

Comment: Although this answer "solve" the error. A better solution is to [properly setup the module system](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) after jdk 9.

Comment: This answer is not useful. It only works by coincidence. Depending on the environment, deleting module-info.java introduces other problems, especially when using components from the JDK that now require modules to be setup properly (like module `java.smartcardio`). Instead, properly setup the module system as pointed out by @samabcde.

Comment: solved the problem!

Answer (score 29):

It seems that **you haven't created a package**. My usual procedure in Eclipse is:

- Create a new Java project
- Inside that project: Create a new package
- Inside that package: Create a new Java class

Eclipse will help you a lot with the settings. Then just copy your code into that class and hit the 'start' button.

Answer (score 6):

by removing module class problem solved for me in eclipse

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: Worked for me too ```module-info.class``` in my case was located at ```build/classes/``` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

i moved my main class and sample.fxml file to a new package that throws this error below

***"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Thomas\eclipse-workspace\HelloWorld\bin
    Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: HelloWorld.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)"***

i moved my class file and fxml file to normal position. it fix my problem. but i have to find why it happends. cheers....

Answer (score 0):

Executing the project from another workspace solved for me in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

create a package and refactor your Main class in that package in your case its HelloWorld then it will run fine.
To understand how modules work in java please watch this spectacular video [MODULES IN JAVA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZQP69NJ6qc)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it according to these steps:

1. right click on your main project name
2. choose the new package and fill in the name
3. choose (radio button) "create package info"
4. click ok
5. finally, in the package explorer, drag your class under the new package which you created

Comment: Using bullet points would make your answer easier to follow. Ex:
- Step 1
- Step 2
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Delete *module-info.java* from your project and run ,it should work. Or Create package and then create class inside package.