# how to run external jar library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just installed eclipse IDE for java and i am unable to execute code from external libraries, i know that we can't execute library code from unnamed package into a named package file, So i've put them both in default package, now i am able to access file from my external JAR library but i'm not able to get through this error, stating cannot connect to VM and some other boot layer error and i have no idea how to get through this...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because of me adding jar library files to MODULEPATH instead of CLASSPATH. You have to add jar files to your CLASSPATH. If you already add jar files to MODLEPATH you have to remove from there and add jar files to CLASSPATH
as on : [Error occurred during initialization of boot layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932777/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer)

Comment: You can also edit the `Is modular` attribute of the jar in the build path (In build path, expand the jar, select "Is modular" and click edit. Then uncheck the box at the top)