# Error occurred during initialization of boot

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

So I recently installed eclipse on my win10 PC, and I created a public class. This is the code:

```
package comex;

public class MyClass { public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Hello World!") } }
```

Next, an error showed:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Ioana Predi\eclipse-workspace\Project1\bin Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: MyClass.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

Then, I deleted the info.java file
and the following error has showed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
   at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:6)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

MyClass should be moved to the package `comex`. Create a directory `comex` in your source directory and move the class into it.

It also appears that you are using the MODULEPATH rather than the class path. This is already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279443/1997707).

Comment: How do I create that directory? Baby steps, please?

Comment: Also, I didn't find any jar files in MODULEPATH expansion.

Comment: Where to create the directory largely depends on your build setup. Wherever your source dir is located you should be able to right click and create a new directory. For the module path did you check the eclipse settings?

Comment: One thing you might try is not to use eclipse but simply go to the directory where the source file is located and type `java MyClass.java`. If you are using java 11+ it should run the single source file.

Comment: Your welcome! If this works can you accept the answer?