# How to fix error Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException, where the JsonFactory not found, How to add it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bigdata

I'm writimg a program in Eclipse for analyzing the Big Data, but when I run it the following exception occurs.

Error occurred during initialization of `boot layer`

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /usr/local/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory not in module
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidModuleDescriptorException when running my first java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133398/invalidmoduledescriptorexception-when-running-my-first-java-app)

Comment: The module descriptor is invalid because it declares a service provider that is missing: probably, in `htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar` the `module-info.java` contains `provides ... with com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` but `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` is missing in that JAR.

Comment: yes, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory is missing in that JAR, so how to add it?

Comment: @NOORALI This isn't a JAR you build yourself, right? If so and if there is no newer version of this JAR, report it to the vendor of the JAR that it is broken (assuming that nobody else has reported it already). Maybe there is another version of the JAR without this error that you can use.

Comment: If the tool you're using was written against an earlier version of the jigsaw spec (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/issues/#VersionsInModuleNames) then you can't have a module called *core4.