# How do I setup Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question on how to start using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

Here is my code:

```
package newpackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\MrJPG\eclipse-workspace\Project IG Bot\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package IGBotPackage not found in module
```

Does anyone know the solution to this? I have tested adding the external jars from Selenium in both the Modulepath and Classpath. However, both seem to have the same result and error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidModuleDescriptorException when running my first java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133398/invalidmoduledescriptorexception-when-running-my-first-java-app)

Comment: If you have a module-info.java in your project, but don't want to use the Java module system, delete the module-info.java.

Answer (score 1):

you need add this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

chromedriver.exe is your chromedriver.exe path    //[download chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

maybe

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Need to be the same as your chrome version
if your chrome is '80.0.3987.106'

need at least these are the same '80.0.3987'

Hope that helps you

Comment: I just tried it, same error. I also checked the chrome driver and my chrome browser and it is the same. Where should I download the chromedriver.exe file to? I have it on my desktop

Comment: You need to copy the path,and modify"C:\\chromedriver.exe",Change to your path

Comment: If you don't know, put it in 'C: \', try it

Comment: So I downloaded the chromedriver from the link you sent. It is a zip file, should I extract it and put it in C: or should I leave it in the zip?

Comment: extract it, get 'chromedriver.exe'

Comment: Put chromedriver.exe in the 'C:\' root directory

Comment: Where is root directory? I put it in Program Files (x86)

Comment: You can put it anywhere, but you have to copy your path, modify'System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");'

Comment: If you put it in the project folder,you can Use this line 'System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");'

Comment: What would the System.setProperty line look like if I leave it in my desktop?

Comment: System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");//you need change userName to your computer user name

Comment: I am now getting this error:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module ProjectIGBot not found

Comment: This is what my code looks like right now: package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass 
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\MrJPG\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://google.com");
 }
}

Comment: Put on C:\\ Have you succeeded?

Comment: No i have not. I have a red underline under both the import statements, WebDriver, and ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Which ChromeDriver version is compatible with which Chrome Browser version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version][1]) to download right version of chromedriver exe.

Place above exe in any(e.g. D:\) path and use below code:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");`

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I have a red underline under both the import statements, WebDriver, and ChromeDriver.

Comment: You have redline means you have not added selenium jar in project. Please add it in project or add maven dependency