# An error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java

I am an absolute beginner when comes to Java and I just installed eclipse. When running my first project I see this strange error that I don't think has anything to do with my code:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Filip\eclipse-workspace\Bomberman\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: CONSTANT_Module at entry 8 is zero length
```

Do you guys have any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidModuleDescriptorException when running my first java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133398/invalidmoduledescriptorexception-when-running-my-first-java-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This might probably be coz while creating your own class you might
> have also accepted to create a default class as prescribed by your
> IDE. If that's the case try this: go to PROJECT folder -> src folder
> -> Default package keep only one class(in which you had written code) and delete another one.

Perhaps downgrading the java version and re-creating the project will help

Comment: I do  not have a default class, however, I do have a default package that I cannot delete.
My classes are under a package that I created.

Comment: Can add screenshot?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the error. Try to recreate the project or install Java 8

Comment: Recreating the project worked. Thank you WBLord!
The only thing I did different compared to the initial project was to add an execution environment from the beginning (the JavaSE-1.7 (jre)). The first time I added it AFTER the creation of the project.

Comment: @Filip No problem, u can mark this like problem solution

Comment: Is there a way I can mark a specific comment or I should just mark  your answer? This was my first question , I am a beginner here as well. :D

Comment: There is no way to mark a comment. I will update the answer so that it is correct.

Comment: Sure, take a look at what I edited in my previous comment as well. May be of help.