# Stuck in importing algs4 in 《algorithm4》 learning

Tags: java

My OS is Windows 10 and I use eclipse to write Java

I downloaded algs4.jar from the [algorithm4 offical network](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/), then used it as my project external jars, but when I try to run the program it keeps giving an error like this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\hw\Downloads\algs4.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: TestAlgs4.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

I google the problem and tried to delete the `TestAlgs4.class` as the former error messages said but it did not work.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 11 Unable to derive module descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682417/java-11-unable-to-derive-module-descriptor)

Comment: There are several different things that could be causing the error.  I would focus on this part: `Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException:... (unnamed package not allowed in module)` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133799/421195 for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I was install alg4 in module path for my project,but it should install in classpath,now I can enjoy the book!